# Help, I can't log in to my account

Tags: support, user-accounts

I had an account on Social Sound Design and now when I try to log in, it wants me to create a new account. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

#### What can I do?

This is a simple issue that can be quickly rectified by following the steps below:

1. Go ahead and create a new account using whatever authentication service you were using previously. Make a note of the profile URL - you can get to the new profile by clicking on your user name at the top of the page. Keep this handy.
2. Locate your original profile URL, if you don't already know it. You can do this by going to the [users page](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users) and entering your user name. Keep this handy as well.
3. [Contact Stack Exchange](https://sound.stackexchange.com/contact/other) and provide them both links, and indicate that you can no longer access your account and have made a new one.
4. Wait for a short while, you'll receive a reply indicating that you can now access your account. We try to process these as soon as they come in during the transition and we have overlapping coverage in many time zones.

Please, ***use the link to contact the team directly*** as that's where they're monitoring for requests to fix this issue. If you post here, it might be a while before someone from the team sees your request.

#### Why did this happen?

This happened because OpenID is handled differently on the Stack Exchange 2.0 platform than it was on the 1.0 platform. Your account is still fine, we just need to fix your credentials.

#### How do you fix this?

By asking you to create a new account to merge with your established account, we ensure that you'll log in properly using the same credentials that you've always used. Once done, it will be as if this never happened, and no remnants of the temporary account you created for merging will remain.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this as well, but I ended up just clicking the 'forgot my password' link.

Put your e-mail address that you used for SSDv1 and they'll send you a link. Click that link and they'll ask for a new password. Once you've entered your new password you'll be able to log in without waiting at all - all done within 15 mins or so.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome Fred! Thanks :) This works if you used Stack Exchange as your OpenID provider on the 1.0 site - if you used Google / Yahoo / Facebook or another provider, you'll probably still need to contact us to sort it out.