# Where is Social sound design?

Tags: discussion

Where is Social sound design forum? How do I login to my previous account? I had accumulated considerable reputation and badges there.

Comment: "social sound design" - that would be a "sound guy" who doesn't hate the entire world - rarer than a hen's teeth.

Answer (score 4):

This is the new SSD forum.  Follow the instructions here to login and link your old account:

[Help, I can't log in to my account](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/help-i-cant-log-in-to-my-account)

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful :)